# Homomorphism between Cartier Divisors and $Pic(X)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Following question to the proof of Cor. 7.1.19 in Liu's "Algebraic Geometry" (p. 257):

[image]

Why it is here already enough to show that every invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ is isomorphic to a sub-$\mathcal{O}_X$-module of $\mathcal{O}_X$?, where $CaCl(X) \to Pic(X)$ is the image from Cartier Divisors modulo priciple Divisors to Picard group (for more detailed description see below):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because of point $(c)$ of the proposition 1.18 (the one you didn't reproduce here). It says that the image of $\mathcal{\rho}$  are the invertible sheaves contained in $\mathcal{K}_X$.

Comment: Sorry, I have attatched it now. So the argument is that every invertible sheaf which is a sub-$\mathcal{O}_X$-module can be embedded canonically in $\mathcal{K}_X$?

Comment: What ?? The point (c) says that the image of $\rho$ are the locally free sheaves which are isomorphic (not necessarily canonically) to a sub-$\mathcal{O}_X$-module of $\mathcal{K}_X$. So if you prove that every locally free sheaf is isomorphic to a sub-$\mathcal{O}_X$-module of $\mathcal{K}_X$, you are done.